# HTML does not load till graph api calls are executed

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

Can a FB canvas app not load any HTML until the Graph API calls are executed?

I have a canvas app whose html does not load until all the graph API calls are executed. I have calls to 3 graph API functions: `user_statuses`, `user_likes` and `user_about_me`.

Steps:

1. https://survey.wwbp.org/?ID=test123 (landing page which leads the user to the app and carries forward the parameters)
2. Log into Facebook.
3. You should get a word cloud based on your statuses.
4. I have a loading gif which asks users to wait till the data is calculated. (it is right before all the other HTML and graph API calls)

I cannot see the loading gif until the Graph API calls are executed.

/** html tag starts here **/

```
/***GET PARAMS***/

$app_data = json_decode($_GET['app_data']);
$var1=$app_data->{'var1'};
$var1=base64_decode($var1);
if(!empty($var1)){ ?>
   <div><img src="my_img_url"/></div>
```

---

/** html ends here **/